# update a record in primefaces datatable

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i am using integration of jsf hibernate spring primefaces.
i want to update a record. but my codes do not work. insert and delete work well. i have no error. please help me to write correct codes.
personeldao.java

```
public class PersonelDao implements IPersonelDao {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
public void updatePersonel(Personel personel) {

    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(personel);
    }
public void deletePersonel(Personel personel) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(personel);

}
```

PersonelService.java

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class PersonelService implements IPersonelService{
    IPersonelDao personeldao;
    public IPersonelDao getPersoneldao() {
        return personeldao;
    }

    public void setPersoneldao(IPersonelDao personeldao) {
        this.personeldao = personeldao;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public void updatePersonel(Personel personel){
    getPersoneldao().updatePersonel(personel);
}
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)

    public void deletePersonel(Personel personel) {
        getPersoneldao().deletePersonel(personel);

    }
```

PersonelBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="personelMB")
@RequestScoped
public class PersonelBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{PersonelService}")
    IPersonelService personelservice;
    List<Personel> personelList;

    private int personel_id;
    private String pname;
    private String pfamily;
    private String paddress;
    private String pphone;
//getter and setter
public void deletePersonel(int personel_id){
        Personel personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
        getPersonelservice().deletePersonel(personel);


    }

    public void updatePersonel(RowEditEvent event){
    Personel personel = (Personel)event.getObject();
    getPersonelservice().updatePersonel(personel);
        //getDataFromDatabase();
    }

}
```

personel.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
>
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>اطلاعات پرسنلی</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h1>اضافه کردن پرسنل جدید</h1>
        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="4" >
              شماره پرسنلی : 
                <h:inputText id="id" value="#{personelMB.personel_id}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="id" >
                </h:inputText>
                <br></br>
                نام : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personelMB.pname}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="Name" >
                </h:inputText>

                 نام خانوادگی: 
                <h:inputText id="family" value="#{personelMB.pfamily}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="family" >
                </h:inputText> 

                آدرس : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="address" value="#{personelMB.paddress}" 
                    cols="30" rows="10" required="true"
                    label="Address" >
                </h:inputTextarea>


          تلفن:  
                <h:inputText id="tel" value="#{personelMB.pphone}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="tel" >
                </h:inputText> 
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="درج اطلاعات" action="#{personelMB.addPersonel()}" />

        </h:form>
 <h2>مشاهده اطلاعات پرسنل</h2>  
 <h:form  prependId="false">  

    <p:dataTable id="pdataTable" var="personel" value="#{personelMB.personelList}" rowKey="#{personelMB.personel_id}" editable="true"
    >  
  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@form" listener="#{personelMB.updatePersonel}"/>
        <f:facet name="header">  
            اطلاعات پرسنل 
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column> 

            <f:facet name="header">  
               شماره پرسنلی  
            </f:facet>  

            <h:outputText value="#{personel.personel_id}" />  

            <f:facet name="footer">  
                کدملی 
            </f:facet>  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام">
        <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pname}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
              <p:inputText value="#{personel.pname}" />
              </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor> 
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام خانوادگی"> 
         <p:cellEditor> 
         <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pfamily}" /> 
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{personel.pfamily}" />
            </f:facet> 
            </p:cellEditor>  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="آدرس"> 
         <p:cellEditor> 
         <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.paddress}" />  
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{personel.paddress}" />
            </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor> 
        </p:column>  
   <p:column headerText="تلفن"> 
   <p:cellEditor> 
   <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pphone}" />
            </f:facet> 
            <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{personel.pphone}" /> 
            </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="حذف">
      <f:facet name="حذف">
         <h:outputText value="" />
      </f:facet>
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="حذف"
                       actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)}"  update="@form" ajax="true"/>
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="ويرايش">

         <p:rowEditor /> 



   </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">  
            تعداد رکورد#{fn:length(personelMB.getPersonelList())} میباشد.  
        </f:facet>  

    </p:dataTable>  

</h:form>  

</h:body>
</html>
```

personel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBLPERSONEL")
public class Personel {
@Id
@Column(name="PERSONEL_ID")
private int personel_id;
@Column(name="PNAME")
private String pname;
@Column(name="PFAMILY")
private String pfamily;
@Column(name="PADDRESS")
private String paddress;
@Column(name="PPHONE")
private String pphone;
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Manager manager;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="personel")
private Set<Stufftransfer> stufftransfers;
public Personel(){

}
public Set<Stufftransfer> getStufftransfers() {
    return stufftransfers;
}
public void setStufftransfers(Set<Stufftransfer> stufftransfers) {
    this.stufftransfers = stufftransfers;
}
public Personel(int personel_id, String pname, String pfamily, String paddress,
        String pphone) {
    super();
    this.personel_id = personel_id;
    this.pname = pname;
    this.pfamily = pfamily;
    this.paddress = paddress;
    this.pphone = pphone;
}
//getter and setter
```

Comment: Can you add the code for Personel class please?

Comment: When you say update doesn't work, what actually happens? Is any exception thrown?

Comment: @JamesB, i have no exception. my codes dont work. when i click on row editor for primefaces and update a record, it didnot work and did not update.

Comment: Have you checked the database directly to confirm the state of the personel row you are updating?

Comment: @JamesB, the row does not update in database. i think my update codes are incorrect. i have no idea.

Comment: @JamesB, my update function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `p:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton`
2. set the update attribute in the `p:commandButton`

remember, it might be a little tricky to find the right id in the update attribute

---

sorry i misunderstood the question
the right answer is :
change your update method to this :

```
public void updatePersonel(RowEditEvent event){
Personel updated = (Pesonel)event.getObject();
//this is the updated value from the dataTable, get the entity from db and do the update
```

}

One more thing: do not update the row on the ajax event, because you didnot update the `personelList` in the update method. That means the `rowEdit` ajax event must be like this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{personelMB.updatePersonel}"/>
```

Comment: Hossein, can you help me? i am struggling with update these days. i am newbie in javaee. i try this but didnot work. <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{personelMB.updatePersonel}"  update="@this" /> public void updatePersonel(RowEditEvent event){
  Personel personel=(Personel)event.getObject();
  getPersonelservice().updatePersonel(personel);
         //getDataFromDatabase();
     }

Comment: Hi Sami, any luck? Was the new answer any helpful?

Comment: hi Hossein, i did what you said. but did not work. i have updated my post. would you please check it? it does not work too.

Comment: is it related to hibernate mapping?

Comment: do not set the update of rowEdit event. after updating the row, you did not update the entire list object, so the update attributes causes the problem. and check that the data base is updated.

Comment: how can i update the entire list object? sorry, i bother you.

Comment: NoProblem bro. you don't need that! but if you think that is necessary, just fill it the same way you did the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ManagedBean's updatePersonel() method, like this

```
    public void updatePersonel(int personel_id,String pname,String pfamily,String paddress,String pphone){
    Personel personel = new Personel();
    personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
    if(personal != null) {
       personel.setPaddress(getPaddress());
       personel.setPersonel_id(getPersonel_id());
       personel.setPfamily(getPfamily());
       personel.setPname(getPname());
       personel.setPphone(getPphone());
       getPersonelservice().updatePersonel(personel_id, pname, pfamily, paddress, pphone);
    }
}
```